# How can we access the data using jQuery for survey monkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

we have a created a survey with above survey link, Now we want to access the data using API 
Console, We have tried with below code.

But we are unable to get the data or result-set. can you help me on this?

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list?
    api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    type: "post", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json", 
    data: JSON.stringify(GetSurvey),
    processData: true, 
    headers: {
        Authorization: "bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Date": "Wed, 20 May 2014 07:15:29 GMT",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
        "Content-Length": "90" 
    }, 
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) { 
        debugger; 
        console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON); 
    } 
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is `Authorization` not quoted?

Comment: Still not working after given the quotation's to Authorization. help me in your way.

Comment: To get better help, create a JSFiddle and make the AJAX request.  You may also want to add an error: hook or check the response message in complete.

Comment: we tried code in JSFiddle, But the thing is we are not getting the result from the JSFiddle.